# matlab and arrays

Tags: matlab

I have a code like this:

```
t = a:(b-a)/10:b;
y = myFunction(t);
```

As far as I guess, this code creates an array `t`, and another array `y` by applying each value of `t` to `myFunction`.

However, if I manually pass the first element of array `t` to `myFunction` like this

```
y = myFunction(t);
```

I will not get the first element of `y` but a different number. Why?

P.S.
`myFunction` looks like this:

```
function res = myFunction(x)
    res = tanh(5*x.^2 + 3*x - 2) + exp((x.^3 + 6*x.^2 + 12*x + 8)/(2*x.^2 + 8*x + 7))-2.0;
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `myFunction` you are performing a right matrix divide (using `/`) whereas you intend to use element-wise divide (using `./`).

Comment: Rats! Beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: @EitanT I have been bitten by this exact bug *so many times* that's it's now the first thing I think of.